# Custom program error 0xbbf, given account is owned by a different program than expected

Tags: anchor, error, devnet, mainnet

I was developing without issue on devnet and then decided to deploy to mainnet. Suddenly the same instruction that used to work on **devnet** gave rise to the following on **mainnet**

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 6: custom program error: 0xbbf
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time debugging and setting `skipPreflight = true`, I was able to detect the the account that was causing the issue.

In my `cargo.toml`, I had a package that had the feature flag for devnet toggled:

```
pkg = { version = "^0.1.14", features = ["devnet"] }
```

The pkg makes use of a program account address that is different from mainnet and devnet. When deploying to mainnet, the feature flag needed to be removed:

```
pkg = { version = "^0.1.14" }
```